# How Amazon API Gateway 's Body Mapping Templates On Integration Request Works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**I am new to AWS API gateway world**, and I followed as API documentation says e.g. also the defined example [here](https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store)

**Now in my work requirements** I would like to have complete caller's HTTP header, caller's IP address details as HTTP request received by API Gateway.

**Yes I referred example as defined** [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) , **It talks about the $context variable**, no where it talks about any example. Yes, I would like to then pass altered information ( via Body Mapping Template to Lambda Function).

**Yes, I also referred  talks about the Request Body Passthrough** - with three options , I selected all three ? [as it says one by one - to understand their working],But its documentation is with all confusion, and no examples available , and nowhere it talks about 'Why'.

[image]

**My Question** :In what situation it will pick the specific template (as I defined 'application/sumit') ?, I tried to use all ways so that template defined by myself, that should be picked but it didn't happen e.g. I sent request from Postman and added content type "application/sumit' that means the content is not json, its my self-defined type, and it should be picked (as body stuff) and then sent to the connected Lambda function, but it didn't work the way I expected(I chose all three options one by one as the default case of doing stuff).

**What exactly the meaning of all three options** :

. **When no template matches the request Content-Type header** ( e.g. means If no Content-Type is abc/abc which doesn't match with any one, then what ?)**Given Information** : The request body will be passed through to the integration when there are no templates matching the request Content-Type header.

. **When there are no templates defined ?**(Recommended) (why its recommended ?, What is the reasoning behind it, Where we can find the answer of it ?)**Given Information** :The request body will be passed through to the integration only when there are no mapping templates defined.

. **Never**  (it means that raw body straight forward should forward to Lambda function, but its not happening that way ?)**Given Information** :The request body will never be passed through to the integration. Requests with a Content-type header that don't match any templates will be rejected with a HTTP 415 response.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the missing piece for you is defining what 'passthrough' is and when it matters. 'Passthrough' means the template transformation is not applied to the incoming request body; instead it is 'passed through' to the backend without transformation. The 'passthroughBehavior' option applies when a client sends a Content-Type that isn' defined in your API. 

Here are more docs: 

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#passthroughBehavior

Comment: When testing each option, you will also need to redeploy each time you change the option, and in Postman you would need to specify a content-type that you haven't defined, like 'application/xml'

Comment: Thanks @JackKohn-AWS you are absolutely right , that I didn't define Content-Type Initially, and later  I defined it and then it worked, but I didn't get proper sense of options available.

Answer (score 2):

We're working on improving the documentation for this.

For now, we would simply recommend using the 2nd option ("when there are no templates defined").

This ensures that as long as you have request templates defined for your method, the request body from the client will never be "passed through" to the endpoint verbatim.

If the client sends "Content-Type" header that matches one of your templates, your mapping template will be applied to the request body and sent to the integration.

If the client sends "Content-Type" header that doesn't match any of your templates, the request will fail with a 415 error.

In some cases you may want to simply proxy the request body sent from the client to the integration. In these cases, the 1st option ("when no template matches") would be appropriate, but please be aware of the security implications of allowing the client to fully control the request body to your integration.

Comment: Yes, It really require to improve the documentation. AWS is superb and solving a lot of problems, but at present I observed that working with AWS require a lot of trial and error method. So few examples in youtube (Video examples) would help.

Comment: I too could use much clearer documentation with possibly some small realistic snippets/example usage. As the OP said, what you guys are making and doing is really great but don't feel as though I can say the same for the documentation personally.

Comment: After more than a year, I still find it hard to understand the documentation and find it difficult to set up a custom integration.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Which concepts are the most difficult to understand from the docs?

Comment: FWIW the AWS documentation is unnecessarily complex. What should take a couple of minutes to find the solution to a problem turns into hours of time wasting. The constant requirement to click next pages is slow, and a lot of the pages are full of fluff and repetition. Look at how Digital Ocean write their docs and articles. Do it like that!